# Comparing values from XML

Tags: php, xml

I have an **XML** with this structure:

```
<WebServiceData>
  <Status>1</Status>
  <Data>
    <Companies>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>115251763</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 1</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>115099315</OwnerNodeID>
        <Share>7.9675</Share>
        <OwnerName>Company 2</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>115082029</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 3</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>115080377</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 4</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112814945</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 5</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112671493</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 6</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115241617</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>108964427</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 7</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115099315</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112867408</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 8</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115099315</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112820093</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 9</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115082029</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>115360800</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 10</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115080377</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112847101</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 11</OwnerName>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <CompanyNodeID>115251763</CompanyNodeID>
        <OwnerNodeID>112905389</OwnerNodeID>
        <OwnerName>Company 2</OwnerName>
      </Item>
    </Companies>
  </Data>
</WebServiceData>
```

I use **SimpleXMLElement** to get the elements:

```
$output = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Then I loop trough the Items:

```
foreach ($output->Data->Companies->Item as $item)
{

}
```

What I must achieve in the code is get owners for each company (companies with `<Level>1</Level>` ) have no owners, so I must compare `$item->CompanyNodeID` with levels larger than 1 (n) with `$item->OwnerNodeID` with levels one less than current level (n-1)

Example:
`$item->CompanyNodeID` with `<Level>2</Level>` is compared to `$item->OwnerNodeID` with `<Level>1</Level>`

Could somebody please help me with some sample code or point me in the right direction?

I know it's a lot of text to read through, but I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SimpleXML and XPath allows you to search the document without having to read through all of the data.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );


$xml = simplexml_load_file("NewFile.xml");

$levelN = $xml->xpath("//Item[Level/text()>1]");

foreach ( $levelN as $level)    {
    $companyNodeID = (string)$level->CompanyNodeID;
    echo "CompanyNodeID=".$companyNodeID.PHP_EOL;
    $owner = $xml->xpath("//Item[OwnerNodeID/text()='{$companyNodeID}']");
    echo "Parent CompanyID=".(string)$owner[0]->CompanyNodeID.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The first XPath query fetches all Item elements where the content of Level is > 1, the second expression fetches the Item element with the matching company ID. I think I've got the correct links between the levels, but the idea could easily be adapted to work with different fields.

This outputs (for your example XML):

```
CompanyNodeID=115099315
Parent CompanyID=115241617
CompanyNodeID=115099315
Parent CompanyID=115241617
CompanyNodeID=115082029
Parent CompanyID=115241617
CompanyNodeID=115080377
Parent CompanyID=115241617
CompanyNodeID=115251763
Parent CompanyID=115241617
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleXMLElement with given data, a nested foreach loop will be the easiest way of archiving your goal.

```
// fist loop, you try to get level2 data
foreach ($output->Data->Companies->Item as $level2Data) {
    // only react if given loop entry is level 2
    if ($level2Data->Level == 2) {
        // as we have a level 2 entry, lets try to find its match on level 1
        foreach ($output->Data->Companies->Item as $level1Data) {
            // check if subentry is level 1 and check if it matches with our given level 2 data
            if ($level1Data->Level == 1 && (int)$level2Data->CompanyNodeID == (int)$level1Data->OwnerNodeID) {
                // here will be a match
                // $level1Data is Level 1 and $level2Data Level 1
                // here you can use above variables to compare whatever you want
                // add your logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.